# Prove: If $x_n=o(\alpha_n)$, then $x_n=O(\alpha_n)$. Show that the converse is not true.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

**Prove: If $x_n=o(\alpha_n)$, then $x_n=O(\alpha_n)$. Show that the converse is not true.**

I know that $x_n=o(\alpha_n)$ means that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n/\alpha_n=0$ and so given $\epsilon>0$ we have that there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$ then $|\frac{x_n}{\alpha_n}|<\epsilon$, then $|x_n|<\epsilon|\alpha_n|$ and so $x_n=O(\alpha_n)$. To see that the converse is not true, we know that $\frac{n+1}{n^2}=O(\frac{1}{n})$, but $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{n+1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+1}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}1+\frac{1}{n}=1\neq 0$.

Is this reasoning right? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your proof is good, but there is easier way to proof the first part:  the definition of small-O is $\forall k>0\exists x_0\forall x>x_0 |f(x)|\le k|g(x)|$ this implies that at least one $k$ have this property, which is the definition of big-O

Comment: $x_n=o(a_n)$ as $n\to \infty$ does not mean that $\lim _{n\to \infty}x_n/a_n =0$ unless $a_n\ne 0$ for all but finitely many $n.$ This is a common slip and likely to cost a mark in school. For example if $x_{2n}=a_{2n}=0$ and $x_{2n+1}=a_{2n+1}/(2n+1)$  then $x_n=o(a_n)$ as $n\to \infty.$...You should erase " then $|\frac {x_n}{a_n}|<\epsilon ,$ " .  Then it's all correct.......BTW another counter-example to the converse is $ x_n=a_n=1$ for all $n.$

Comment: The def'n of $x_n=o(a_n)$ as $n\to \infty$ is that for all $r>0$ there exists $ m $ such that $n>m\implies |x_n|\leq r|a_n|.$

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. Any example where $a_n=x_n$, such as $a_n=x_n=1, \forall n$ or $a_n=x_n=n, \forall n$ would do.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems right. I would've added that

$$\forall n>1:\frac{n+1}{n^{2}}<2\frac{1}{n}\Longrightarrow\frac{n+1}{n^{2}}=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

so your reasoning will be complete.